# Manjaro install error - Bad source

Tags: manjaro

I am trying to install Manjaro on an unallocated partition. I download everything from their site using torrent. I use YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer) to make bootable USB. All goes well but when I start Manjaro, I select the replace partition option and try to install, I get this error:

```
Bad source
source="/bootmnt/manjaro/x86_64/root-image.sqfs"
```

At first I thought it maybe a corrupted file so I redo it all but again same error occurs.

Comment: Probably not the case here, but i ran into problems creating usb boot sticks when using a faulty usb3 port to write the image. Its worth a try at least.

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error message when booting from a Multibooting USB (in my case prepared with multibootusb; while you're using YUMI). I solved the issue by comparing the path in `/etc/calamares/modules/unpackfs.conf` (Manjaro live via USB) with the actual path (check in a terminal).

After I changed the path in `unpackfs.conf` accordingly, the installation was able to continue. e.g.:

```
---
unpack:
    - source: "/run/miso/bootmnt/multibootusb/manjaro-mate-18.0.4-stable-x86_64/manjaro/x86_64/rootfs.sfs"
      sourcefs: "squashfs"
      destination: ""
    - source: "/run/miso/bootmnt/multibootusb/manjaro-mate-18.0.4-stable-x86_64/manjaro/x86_64/desktopfs.sfs"
      sourcefs: "squashfs"
      destination: ""
```

see [ref](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/error-bad-source-source-run-miso-bootmnt-manjaro-x86-64-rootfs-sfs/68241/13)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bad-source-error-in-installation/8737/6) endorses using **dd** to create the installer, not **YUMI**.

I don't know if all the UEFI stuff applies in your case.

Also, make sure you're not trying to install a 64-bit image on a 32-bit device. Been there, done that!